# Can I play Destiny without PlayStation Plus?

Tags: ps4, psn, destiny

Today I went to a store to buy Destiny for PS4. I have been played Destiny in the demo 1 month ago. I play just a few hours per week and I don't want have the PlayStation Plus signature.

At the Store the guys advise me to play Destiny I must have the PlayStation plus signature to play this game.

I would like know is it true, why I'm not able to play by myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you **can play Destiny without PlayStation Plus**, PlayStation Plus is required to play online.

If you are intending to play single player, you have no problem, however keep in mind that **Destiny focuses a lot of its content for multiplayer/ online, and without PlayStation Plus you are likely to miss out on a lot of what the game had to offer.**

Answer (score 5):

As you can read on the bungie FAQ/Help: Yes, **you can play it without PSN+** (corrected my first answer, sorry for that), **but not access all features**:

> **Q. Does Destiny require PlayStation®Plus or Xbox Live Gold?**
>
> No, PlayStation®Plus and Xbox Live are not required to play Destiny. However, PlayStation®Plus or Xbox Live Gold is required to access some content. Please see below for more information.
>
> **What is PlayStation®Plus?**
>
> PlayStation®Plus works differently for the PlayStation 3 and PlayStation 4 consoles. 
>   PS4: PlayStation®Plus is required to join Fireteams and play some online activities, such as Strikes, the Raid, and the Crucible.
>   PS3: PlayStation®Plus is not required.
>
> **Xbox Live Gold**
>
> **What is Xbox Live?**
>
> Xbox Live Gold is required to join Fireteams and play some online activities on the Xbox One or Xbox 360, such as Strikes, the Raid, and the Crucible.
>
> Please note: Xbox Live Gold is required to download and play on Xbox platforms. 48-hour, 7-day, and 14-day Xbox Live Gold trials are not supported on Xbox 360.

Source: https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/12135