# How to play destiny without Internet connection?

Tags: destiny

Is it possible to play Destiny without an Internet connection?

Answer (score 5):

No, Destiny requires an internet connection at all times in order to play.

This is true even for solo-play.

Comment: Not only an internet connection.   You also need either XBoxLive or the PS equivalent.

Comment: @CPerkins, not exactly. For PS, not all the features will be available, but you still [can play without PS Plus](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226281/can-i-play-destiny-without-playstation-plus).